# How to Properly set an integer value in NSDictionary?

Tags: objective-c

The following code snippet:

```
NSLog(@"userInfo: The timer is %d", timerCounter);

NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:timerCounter] forKey:@"timerCounter"];

NSUInteger c = (NSUInteger)[dict objectForKey:@"timerCounter"];
NSLog(@"userInfo: Timer started on %d", c);
```

produces output along the lines of:

```
2009-10-22 00:36:55.927 TimerHacking[2457:20b] userInfo: The timer is 1
2009-10-22 00:36:55.928 TimerHacking[2457:20b] userInfo: Timer started on 5295968
```

(FWIW, timerCounter is a NSUInteger.)

I'm sure I'm missing something fairly obvious, just not sure what it is.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You should use `intValue` from the received object (an `NSNumber`), and not use a cast:

```
NSUInteger c = [[dict objectForKey:@"timerCounter"] intValue];
```

Comment: Actually, for NSUInteger, you should use `-unsignedIntegerValue`.

Comment: (And `+[NSNumber numberWithUnsignedInteger:]` to create the NSNumber, if it really is meant to be unsigned.)

Comment: You can use `@(timerCounter)` instead of `[NSNumber numberWithInteger: timerCounter]`

Answer (score 11):

Dictionaries always store objects. NSInteger and NSUInteger are not objects. Your dictionary is storing an NSNumber (remember that `[NSNumber numberWithInteger:timerCounter]`?), which is an object. So as epatel said, you need to ask the NSNumber for its `unsignedIntegerValue` if you want an NSUInteger.

Answer (score 0):

Or like this with literals:

```
NSUInteger c = ((NSNumber *)dict[@"timerCounter"]).unsignedIntegerValue;
```

You must cast as NSNumber first as object pulled from dictionary will be id_nullable and so won't respond to the value converting methods.